# Responsive div with image aligned 100% to text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image aligned right of some text/lists while having the image still be 100% in height and within the div. So far I've come close but the image is always overlapping the bottom of the div. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's the code I've come up with so far, I've been using inline CSS but once I've figured it out it'll be in a separate CSS file. Any help is really appreciated, been trying to figure this out for days!

```
  <div style="background: #000; width: 90%; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; text-align:left; border: 1px solid #95403c;">
    <p>
    <img style="float: right; margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px; width: 355px;" src="" />
    <div align="center">

    <h1>Gold (proper style coming soon)</h1><br />
    <clear>
      <u>All Edited Videos Include:</u>
        <ul style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
          <li>60-90 Minute Interview Documentary</li>
          <ul><li>B-Roll Footage</li>
          <li>Incorporation of personal video clips (up to 15) and photographs (up to 125)</li>
          <li>Interview Transcript</li></ul>
          <li>1-2 Minute Individual Clips of Family Members </li>
          <li>Up to 5 individuals will share a favorite memory with or express their love for the subject </li>
          <li>5-10 Minute Prized Possession</li>
          <li>The subject will share and describe their most prized possession</li>
          <li>Behind The Scenes Photographs</li></ul>
        </ul>

    <clear>
    <div style=" display: inline-block;  vertical-align: top;">
      <u>You Will Receive:</u>
        <ul  style="display: inline-block;  text-align: left;">
          <li>USB flash drive with all edited video files,<br /> pictures, and interview transcript</li>
          <li>15 DVDs</li>
            <ul><li>Customized printed DVDs</li>
            <li>Customized menu and chapters</li>
            <li>Hard cases with customized insert</li></ul>
        </ul></div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;  vertical-align: top;">
      <u>All Edited Videos Include:</u>
        <ul  style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
        <li>Customized Titles</li>
        <li>Customized Graphics</li>
        <li>Music</li>
        <li>Sound Design</li>
        <li>Color Correction</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <clear>

    <br style="clear: both;" /></p>

</div>
```

Comment: You have `<clear>` in your HTML? -  Also inline styles?

Comment: You first need to make sure you are using correct HTML syntax. I'm not sure what the `<clear>` tag is used for. You cannot have `<ul>` as a direct child of `<ul>`. `align="center"` is no longer used as standard - use css instead. [Here](https://validator.w3.org/) is a html validator tool where you can check your syntax. I would also recommend against using inline style.

Comment: jQuery is an option ? If yes; you can set the height of you're image to the size of the element left (And this will be responsive !)

Comment: This is what it looks like with valid HTML & extracted CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/bodL9vtb/ Now. Perhaps you could explain what this should look loke with an actual image?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks so much for your help, Paulie! The image is a stock image [link] (http://imgur.com/rGyvNOu) but it's cropped into the maroon box in the original screenshot with the height of it being the full height of the div. Hope that makes sense..